Gitlab Runner with cygwin shell executor fails at repository setup
I'm trying to run Gitlab Runner with cygwin's bash as shell.
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
connection_max_age = "15m0s"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "DESKTOP-RRN90RT"
  url = "https://example.com/"
  id = 16
  token = "fooobar"
  token_obtained_at = 2024-05-28T00:10:02Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "bash"
  builds_dir="/cygdrive/c/Gitlab-Runner/builds/"
  cache_dir="/cygdrive/c/Gitlab-Runner/cache/"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

When submitting a job the following output can be seen:
Running with gitlab-runner 15.11.0 (436955cb)
  on DESKTOP-RRN90RT HMdpAXqu, system ID: s_f734b6ab6237
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on DESKTOP-RRN90RT...
Getting source from Git repository 00:00
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
error: could not lock config file /cygdrive/c/Gitlab-Runner/builds/HMdpAXqu/0/myproject/astraeajvm.tmp/git-template/config: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

How do I configure cygwin with Gitlab Runner properly?
cygwin's bash is present in Windows Path variable. So I can run bash command on host and enter cygwin shell.
Also Gitlab Runner is using User Account.
Looking from bash on the host machine git template config file is present:
[init]
        defaultBranch = none
[fetch]
        recurseSubmodules = false
[http "https://example.com"]
        sslCAInfo = C:\\Gitlab-Runner\\builds\\HMdpAXqu\\0\\myproject\\astraeajvm.tmp\\CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE


Though I don't see CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE present (perhaps it's created while Job is running?)
Also gitlab-runner logs don't show anything interesting in particular:
WARNING: Failed to process runner                   builds=0 error=exit status 1 executor=shell runner=HMdpAXqu
WARNING: Starting graceful shutdown, waiting for builds to finish  StopSignal=quit builds=0

This question tackles this exact issue but for me for some reason starting service (using gitlab-runner start) from cygwin bash doesn't change anything and results in same behavior. I also tried running Gitlab Runner inside the shell itself (gitlab-runner run). Result is the same.

I have the exact same error and have not been figure out the reason for this . were you able to figure this out ?
